# How do you set href attribute of anchor tag that is within a repeater in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

normally on would use the following  :-

aspx page:-

```
<a ID="a1" href="javascript:void(0);">Link1 </a>
```

code behind:-

```
a1.HRef="www.mySite.com/mypage.aspx";
```

how do u set this HRef attribute in case the anchor tag is within a repeater ?

Comment: cool..thnx all for answering :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For example, in the `ItemDatabound` event:

```
protected void rptData_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlAnchor a1 = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("a1");
    a1.HRef = "www.mySite.com/mypage.aspx";
}
```

Also, don't forget to put `runat="server"` on that anchor

```
<a ID="a1" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0);">Link1 </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the ItemDatabound event.

Check out: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c12065

Answer (score 2):

First you need to make your control server side by putting `runat="Server"`

```
    <a runat="Server" ID="a1" href="javascript:void(0);">Link1 </a>

protected void rptOuter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
       // Find your anchor here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the event [ItemDatabound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) of your repeater:

```
((HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("a1")).HRef = "www.mySite.com/mypage.aspx";
```