# How to set href attribute of anchor tag that is within a repeater in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one master page in that anchor tag is der in that i am using href and i have to bind href from code behind so please give me solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asp:HyperLink` with some ID and then set its `NavigateUrl` property in the code behind. HyperLink documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: actually i want to set two different url in code behind so pls give me solution.

Comment: do you mean that your repeater will have two items?

Comment: yes i have two set of url (a.aspx and b.aspx ) how can i pass this to href?

Comment: I don't know what you mean - a single link can only point to one target, not two.

Comment: no see i have two pages  (1. a.aspx and 2. b.aspx) k.here "<a tabindex="-1" id="portpolio" href="User-Portfolio.aspx">Sample Ordered Packs
        </a>" in that href is there na based on condition i want pass the url to href like a.aspx or b.aspx

Comment: see this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976659/how-do-you-set-href-attribute-of-anchor-tag-that-is-within-a-repeater-in-code-be?rq=1

Comment: but that event is not fireing?

Answer (score 0):

In the master page, change the anchor to a Asp:HyperLink server control.

Then in the `PageLoad` event of each page, a.aspx and b.aspx, set the following code:

```
Dim mMaster As MyMasterPage = CType(Me.Master, MyMasterPage )
mMaster.portpolio.NavigateUrl = "a.aspx"  ' or b.aspx
```

Remember to change `MyMasterPage` to match the class of your master page. Thats it!